# Find a sine function that intersects at ($y = 0$) for a given $x$

Tags: graphing-functions

[image: Graph]If (for say, visual aesthetics) I would like to plot the graph of a sine wave on a 2D graph that intersects the $x$ axis with value of $y =0$ when $x$ is some arbitrary integer - how would I go about doing that?

Obviously it is trivial to find this function for the initial intersection; I'd like to investigate whether there exists a method to generate a wave that crosses this point after its first period.

To make it clear: I know *how* to plot the graph, but not how to find the seed value for the function.

**Edit - added image:**
Apologies, I couldn't find a way to word the question for the actual outcome I wanted so tried to get a foothold by finding the intersect as $y =0$. I'm interested in getting all waves that 'peak' at a given value for $x$. I'm struggling a little with the terminology.

Comment: harmonic functions (e.g. (co)sine) have three parameters: frequency, phase and amplitude, for what conditions they must satisfy in your request?

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which is how the math on this site is rendered so beautifully :)

Comment: Have you heard about Fourier Transforms? You can use them to fit to pretty much any function, and they are build with sines and cosines.

Comment: What do you mean by "crossing this point after the first period" ? Once the curve has passed this point, it will never be back there again...?

Comment: It's not clear to us what you are looking for. The function
$$y(t)=A \sin(\omega(t-x))$$ is a sine wave of amplitude $A$, frequency $f=\omega/(2\pi)$ and satisfies $y(x)=0$. But what exactly do you want?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not explaining this properly. I'll update my question with an image in a second

Comment: There will be infinitely-many waves that peak at a given $x$ (turn the knobs on frequency and amplitude). Still not understanding what it is you're looking for.

Comment: @sasha I'm interested only in integer n solutions for y = sin(x*PI /n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix the amplitude and phase, then the waves that first peak at $x = x_0$ are given by:

$$y = \sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{n}\left ( x - x_0 + \frac{n}{2}\right )\right )$$

These have period, amplitude, and phase of $2n$, $1$, and $x_0-\frac{\pi}{2}$, respectively.

Try it out [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin%20(%20(Pi%2F15)*(x-10%2B15%2F2))).